# Php shell_exec() Permission Denied Using gpg Command

Tags: php, linux, gnupg, permission-denied, shell-exec

The error message:

> gpg: Fatal: can't create directory '/srv/http/.gnupg': Permession
>   Denied

The script:

```
<?php
    $cmd = "/usr/bin/gpg -e -a -r kioccio@gmail.com prova 2>&1";
    echo shell_exec($cmd);
?>
```

Why I don't have the permission?

P.S.Without 2>&1 the command doesn't work.
P.S. adding 'sudo' at the command doesn't work

I am the user simone

[image]

Comment: you are executing this script using cli sapi ? or http server?

Comment: I am executing http server with apache on manjaro

Comment: apache2 often is running under `www-data` user, which is had not enough permissions -for security reasons-

Comment: Thanks very much, How can I add this user to group simone in order to allow him to write on the directory?

Comment: this is the last thing you may want to do, you may instead of that change the config of `gpg` to make it use another directory and give that directory 777 permission

Answer (score 0):

[shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php) or any other command with shell interaction uses the user and group setted into httpd.conf. If that user doesn't have the proper permissions to manipulate the folder and the bins that you want, you'll experience those errors.

I recommend to study about permissions in the linux system and the proper way to give them without compromise the security of your system, some routines must be in a sandbox to save about malicious commands.